# When I use DES algorithm I convert byte[] to String and convert this String to byte[], and these two byte[] become different

Tags: java

When I use DES algorithm I convert byte[] to String and convert this String to byte[], and these two byte[] become different:

```
String str = "lszzz";
String password = "12343213";
byte[] result = Des.encrypt(str.getBytes("utf-8"), password);
String res=new String(result,"utf-8");
System.out.println(result+" dividing line "+res.getBytes());
```

The running answer is

```
[B@182decdb dividing line [B@26f0a63f；
```

Why are these two `byte[]` different, and how can I can get the same `byte[]`?

Comment: Because you need to print the arrays one byte at a time.

Comment: But these two byte array are different , when i using the other byte[] in my desc decoding part, it goes wrong;

Comment: Let me rephrase that: what that `System.out.println` prints is irrelevant because you're printing (the addresses of) two separate arrays, not their contents. If you have a problem with their contents please show a piece of code which shows that wrong behavior.

Comment: What is the reason to create a String from resulted `byte[]`? Just to print it to console to see content?

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here.

When you concatenate a String with a byte array (which you do twice in `result + " dividing line " + res.getBytes()`) you are calling `toString()` on a `byte[]`.  When you call `toString()` on *any* array, you get a value of the form

```
  [<internal-type-name>@<identity-hashcode>
```

This does not represent the *contents* of the array.  It represents the identity of the array.

So, in this case, `[B@182decdb dividing line [B@26f0a63f` only tells you that these are byte arrays and that they are not the same object.  It does not explain anything.

The second issue is that you can't treat an arbitrary byte sequence as a UTF-8 encoding.  Not every sequence of arbitrary bytes is a *valid* UTF-8 encoding.

The `Des.encrypt` call is producing a byte array containing arbitrary binary bytes.  When you treat an array containing arbitrary bytes as UTF-8 encoded ... and decode it into a `String`, the process is lossy.  When you then take the `String` value in `res` and then attempt to encode it as UTF-8, it is *unlikely* that the bytes you will get will be the same as the bytes that you started with.

The solution depends on what you are trying to do here:

- If you want to store or transmit binary data as binary:

  - use a `BLOB` database type
  - use `InputStream` / `OutputStream`
  - possibly use `DataInputStream` / `DataOutput` or `ObjectInputStream` / `ObjectOutputStream`
- If you are trying to turn the encrypted data into a robust form that can be transmitted through a "text only" channel, use `Base64` encoding.
- If want to pretend that your bytes are text, you could encode them as ISO-8859-1 aka LATIN-1.  There is a 1-to-1 correspondence between the 256 codes of ISO-8859-1 and the first 256 Unicode codepoints.  So if you pretend that that your binary is ISO-8859-1, you can decode them to a string, encode them back to ISO-8859-1, and get the bytes that you started with.  (This is conceptually broken ... but it works.)

---

Now a strict reading of the ISO-8859-1 spec says that the "conceptually broken" approach *should not work*.  However, the following test code demonstrates that it does.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
        byte[] data = new byte[256];
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
            data[i] = (byte) i;
        }
        String s = new String(data, "ISO-8859-1");
        data = s.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
            if (data[i] != ((byte) i)) {
                System.out.println("mismatch: " +  data[i] + " != " +
                   ((byte) i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We can put this down to the way that the ISO-8859-1 encoder / decoder classes are implemented in Java.

Comment: There is no 1-on-1 correspondence between all 256 byte values and ISO-8859-1, specifically the ranges 0x00-0x1F and 0x7F-0x9F are undefined in ISO-8859-1, Windows-1252 (Cp1252) is very similar to ISO-8859-1, and does map **most** bytes, with the exception of 0x81, 0x8D, 0x8F, 0x90 and 0x9D. So encoding to those code pages is stilll lossy

Comment: Hmmm ... let me check that.  (I have seen people say this works in Java.)

Comment: There are some variants where the 0x00-0x1F and  0x7F - 0x9F is mapped to the C0 and C1 control codes, but those aren't actually defined in the standard. It looks like Java actually does map to C0 and C1, but that would possibly prevent interchange with systems using the 'standard' definition.

Comment: Well ... in fact ... it works using Java 11.0.7.  From this we conclude that the Java implementation of the ISO-8859-1 behaves as I said *irrespective* of the spec for the character encoding.